# React - WhiteSpace between 2 Collapsible Tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 [collapsible](https://github.com/glennflanagan/react-collapsible) tags in my code that are next to each other:

```
<Collapsible trigger="text 1 " >
  //some html content here
</Collapsible> 
<Collapsible trigger="text 2 " >
  //some other html content here
</Collapsible>
```

[Click here to see image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy0tC.png)
However, when I close the collapsible associated with 'text 1', there still is a whitespace that remains between 'text 1' and the next collapsible element. Ideally, I would want a sliding effect so that when I close the first collapsible, the second one's content automatically moves up and subsequently moves down on opening the first collapsible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from

```
//some html content here
```

to be something like

```
{this.state.isExpanded && (/* some html content here */)
```

If your `isExpanded` state is `false`, `this.props.children` will not render (so there is no reserved space anymore)

see this [example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jp14pvn263)

edit: sorry about my previous answer, to render nothing you need to return `null`

Comment: "That is because React has reserved the space for all rendered components" --- what does this exactly mean in terms of virtual DOM, DOM and HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure where I read it from since I have read it a long time ago but if I remember correctly, it's DOM.

Comment: The it's not obvious how "reserved space" in DOM is relevant to problems with laying it out.

Comment: Maybe I use the wrong word, sorry about my poor English. :(

Comment: I think the problem is irrelevant to react: it's solely about html and css.

Comment: so would it be something like {this.state.isExpanded === true ? (/*html content*/) : null } ?? It did not work for me

Comment: @AnirudhMittal Did you check my example code yet? Is that the result you want?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, yes it did help. Thank you